# SQL need to get results with zero values

Tags: sql

I have a table CITY_PEOPLE with cityName and peopleName as two column names and another table PEOPLE_ALIVE with peopleName and aliveStatus column names

aliveStatus can have Y or N

I want to get the count of people alive in the city and the city name

With below query, I am able to get the count if count > 0

```
SELECT cityName, count(*) noOfPeopleAlive 
FROM CITY_PEOPLE b 
WHERE peopleName in (SELECT peopleName FROM PEOPLE_ALIVE where aliveStatus='Y') 
GROUP BY b.cityName
```

but I want to have the list of cities with count = 0 as well. How can I get ?

Comment: Is peopleName first and last name? How do you know you won't have 2 "John Smith" in one city?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Left Join`.

```
SELECT cityName, count(p.peopleName) noOfPeopleAlive 
FROM CITY_PEOPLE b 
LEFT JOIN PEOPLE_ALIVE p
ON p.peopleName = b.peopleName
AND p.aliveStatus = 'Y'
group by b.cityName
```

Also note: Just glaring at your query, if you're joining on a person's name, it's pretty common to have people with the same name which is going to make your life difficult.

Comment: This doesn't work; `count(*)` will return 1 for cities with no people because it doesn't distinguish between cases where there's a record in `p` and those where there's not.

Comment: Could you just `count(peopleName)`? If there are no people in the city, then that would return 0.

Comment: You may need  "count(p.peoplename) noOfPeopleAlive "

Answer (score 1):

A left outer join will solve your problem

```
SELECT cityName, count(*) noOfPeopleAlive 
FROM CITY_PEOPLE b 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PEOPLE_ALIVE p
ON p.peopleName = b.peopleName
AND p.aliveStatus = 'Y'
GROUP BY b.cityName
```

Answer (score 1):

Weird table structure, but this will work:

```
select
    C.cityName,
    noOfPeopleAlive = sum(case P.aliveStatus when 'Y' then 1 else 0 end)
from
    CITY_PEOPLE C
    left join PEOPLE_ALIVE P on C.peopleName = P.peopleName
group by
    C.cityName;
```